# Como alterar os valores dentro do array?

Tags: java, array

Estou fazendo o seguinte exercício:

Um programa que descubra o menor número dentro de uma array
e atribua esse valor a todos os elementos da array.

E meu código até o momento está assim:

```
public class Exercicio02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int valor[] = new int[] { 2, 6, 8, 12, 54 };

        int menor = 9999;

        for (int i = 0; i < valor.length; i++) {
            if (valor[i] < menor) {
                menor = valor[i];
            }
        }

        
        System.out.println("Menor valor = " + menor);

    }
}
```

Agora eu preciso substituir todos os valores do array para esse menor so que não faço ideia de como fazer isso de uma vez só

Answer (score 0):

Tem duas maneiras de você fazer isso, a maneira mais didática:

```
for (int i = 0; i < valor.length; i++) {
    valor[i] = menor; 
}
```

Ou usando a API do java pra fazer isso em uma unica linha / chamada de função:

```
java.util.Arrays.fill(valor, menor); // A função fill recebe um array e um valor para setar todas as posições naquele valor
```